# Carbon date parsing issue in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I am using Laravel 5.6, PHP 7.2.10

```
2018-12-24 12:42:00.0 is getting converted to "Dec 24 2018, 12:12 pm"
```

Output of tinker

```
$dt = App\Video::find(8611)->created_at;
=> Illuminate\Support\Carbon @1545655320 {#3075
     date: 2018-12-24 12:42:00.0 UTC (+00:00),
   }
>>> Carbon\Carbon::parse($dt)->format('M d Y, h:m a')
=> "Dec 24 2018, 12:12 pm"
>>>
```

what I am missing or doing wrong or this is any known behavior of carbon.

Comment: `$dt` is already a carbon date why do you need to run it through a `parse`?

Comment: @apokryfos you are correct I updated it on my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working format is

```
$dt->format('Y-m-d H:i a')
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

format('M d Y, h:m a')

try

format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u')

Comment: I do not need that format, By the way output is `"2018201820182018-DecDec-MonMon 1212:1212:0000"
`

Comment: That gives me `>>> Carbon\Carbon::parse($dt)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u')
=> "2018-12-24 12:42:00.000000"` any way thank you so much for your help, I got the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

Hope help you:

```
 Carbon\Carbon::parse($dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')->format('M d Y, h:m a')
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I am getting this error. `\Carbon\Carbon::parse($dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')->format('M d Y, h:m a')
PHP Warning:  timezone_open(): Unknown or bad timezone (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss) in
D:/work/www/WFM/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Carbon.php on line 374
InvalidArgumentException with message 'Unknown or bad timezone (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm
:ss)'
`

Comment: sorry for hungry answer, try to:
Carbon\Carbon::parse($dt)->format('M d Y, h:i a')

Comment: hungry answer!! what is that bro, you tried to help me, I am happy about that.

Comment: hurry answer :)))